# Rails loop through a database table and reject one object by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm searching for objects inside a database table according to an `id`:

```
def edit
  @attachments = Attachment.where(item_id: @item.id)
end
```

and inside the view I'm trying to reject the `no-image.jpg` image like this:

```
<% @attachments.reject { |attachment| attachment.image.file.identifier == "no-image.jpg" }.each do |attachment| %>
    <%= image_tag(attachment.image.url(:mini))%>
    <%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_attachment_path(attachment), :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Now even though the file `no-image.jpg` exists inside the loop when I debug it, it's giving the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Items#edit
undefined method `identifier' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x007fb193633520>
```

The error is in this line:

```
<% @attachments.reject { |attachment| attachment.image.file.identifier == "no-image.jpg" }.each do |attachment| %>
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I am guessing you have a default image set (to `no-image.jpg`) ? So actually you want to block attachments without image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nathanvda , I want show all the images except for the `no-image.jpg`, if it exists inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing you also write `attachment.image.url` I assume `image` is the field where the image is stored inside the `Attachment` class, so in that case you should just write

```
attachment.image.identifier
```

I think `attachment.image_identifier` is also possible.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda, this worked just fine for me `attachment.image_identifier`